# How to count the sum of values in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It's such an easy task, but somehow I'm stuck. I have an array of objects of product items that looks like this:

`[{id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2}, {id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4}, {id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2}]`

I need to count the total price of all items, which should be: the price of a specific product multiplied by quantity and the same for previous products. Example: (30*2)+(20*4)+(10*2)

My code looks like this:

```
    items.forEach(function (item) {
           let sum = item.price * item.quantity;
           console.log(sum);
});
```

The output looks like:

```
60
80
20
```

But I need to count the total which should be 160 and render it to the page and somehow I can't figure out the way to do that

Comment: So move your `let sum` outside of the for loop ...  Seriously, your one step away from solving this yourself.

Comment: You need to use reduce function from JavaScript.

Comment: `.reduce((p, { price, quantity }) => p + price*quantity, 0)`

Comment: I notice that you don't use `+` anywhere in your code; that's a bad sign if you are trying to compute a sum.

Comment: @Taplar: *at least* one step, but more than just moving `let sum` outside of loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter more than one, sure.  But enough that it warrents a StackOverflow question? -_-

Comment: @Taplar: "Seriously, your one step away from solving this yourself."

Comment: Three steps.  Move the let outside and initialize to 0.  Change the inner operation to `+=`.  And move the console.log after the loop.  All three steps apparently require a S.O. question for someone to figure out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method is best suited for operations like this (sum total).

In my answer below, `sum` is the accumulator and is initially set to `0`. The accumulator is the value previously returned by the callback. The `{ price, quantity }` is [object destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) of the current value.

```js
const sumTotal = arr =>
  arr.reduce((sum, { price, quantity }) => sum + price * quantity, 0)

const data = [
  { id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2 },
  { id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4 },
  { id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2 },
]

const total = sumTotal(data)

console.log(total) // 160
```

Here is a similar [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Sum_of_values_in_an_object_array).

Comment: Here is a similar [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Sum_of_values_in_an_object_array). `sum` is the accumulator, which is initially set to 0. The `{ price, quantity }` is [object destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) of the current value. The return value of the callback at each step becomes the accumulator (`sum`) value of the next step.

Answer (score 3):

You are close to getting the answer. I modified slightly your code and get the expected result. See below.

```js
const items = [{id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2}, {id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4}, {id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2}];

const sumItems = () => {
let sum = 0;
items.forEach(function(item) {
    let calculation = item.price * item.quantity;
    sum += calculation;
})
console.log(sum);
};

sumItems();
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let items = [
  {id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2}, 
  {id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4}, 
  {id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2}
]

let total = items.reduce((sum,item) => sum + item.price * item.quantity, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var products =[{id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2}, {id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4}, {id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2}]
console.log(products.map(x=> x.price*x.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external library, I suggest using the `sumBy` method from `lodash` [library](https://lodash.com/docs/#sumBy)

Example:

```
_.sumBy(items, function(item) { return item.price * item.quantity; });
```